# Index of Embedding layer with zero padding in Keras

Tags: deep-learning, gensim, keras

I am building an RNN model in Keras for sentences with word embeddings from gensim. I am initializing the embedding layer with GloVe vectors. Since this is a sequential model and sentences have variable lengths, vectors are zero-padded. e.g.

```
[0, 0, 0, 6, 2, 4]
```

Let's say the GloVe vectors have dimensions `[NUM_VOCAB, EMBEDDING_SIZE]`. The zero index is masked (ignored) so to get the proper indexing of words, do we add an extra column to the GloVe matrix so the dimensions are: `[NUM_VOCAB+1, EMBEDDING_SIZE]`?

Seems like there is an unnecessary vector that the model will estimate unless there is a more elegant way.

```
glove = Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format(filename)
embedding_matrix = np.vstack([np.zeros(EMBEDDING_SIZE), glove.syn0])

model = Sequential()

# -- this uses Glove as inits
model.add(Embedding(NUM_VOCAB, EMBEDDING_SIZE, input_length=maxlen, mask_zero=True,
                           weights=[embedding_matrix]))

# -- sequence layer
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=False, init='orthogonal'))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))

...
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you every figure this out?

Comment: I just appended zero (or random) vector(s) to the original embedding matrix. So if I use index 0 for padding and index 1 for OOV, the original embedding increases by two rows. Then I +2 to each word id when vectorizing each word. I think this works.

Comment: If you add your comment as an answer before my bounty expires, I'd be happy to award it to you (I think it has ~ an hour left)

Comment: ah crap, it already expired.  Oh well.  Thanks for the comment, it answered my question.